# Reference Request: James reduced product

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I would like to quickly learn the basics of [James reduced product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_reduced_product) (also called James construction). Anyone know some suitable material for beginners?

Comment: There is a section in Hatcher's book on it I think.

Comment: @Hanno, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology mentions James construction; but I am not sure if it is the ideal place to start for beginners.